# What's a Data Generation Plan ( MS Visual Studio )?

Tags: sql-server, database, data-generation

In Microsoft Visual Studio Team Edition for Database Professionals , what does the **Data Generation Plan wizard** actually do ?
Is it a tool that dumps random data into my tables so I can test my database-driven application ??! 
Or is it a tool that pulls `stuff` from database A so I can later insert the `same stuff` into database B ?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Data Generation Plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833211%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> You can use Microsoft Visual Studio Team Edition for Database
>   Professionals to generate meaningful data for testing. You can
>   generate random data, generate data from existing data sources, and
>   control many aspects of data generation.